# Dotted polyline on Google Maps IOS-Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to draw a dotted polyline on Google Maps using swift language, can anyone to help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
private var polylineArray:[GMSCircle] = [GMSCircle]() //global variable


//MARK: Find a route between to coordinates and draw the route

private func callingDistanceAPI() {
   let origin = "\(37.778483),\(-122.513960)"
   let destination = "\(37.706753),\(-122.418677)"
   let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving&key=[YOUR-API-KEY]"

Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
   guard let data = response as? [String:Any],
            let preRoutes = data["routes"] as? NSArray,
            let preRoute = preRoutes.firstObject,
            let routes = preRoute as? NSDictionary,
            let routeOverviewPolyline:NSDictionary = routes.value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as? NSDictionary,
            let polyString = routeOverviewPolyline.object(forKey: "points") as? String else {
            return
        }
      self.showPath(polyStr: polyString)
    }
}



//MARK: Draw polyline

func showPath(polyStr :String) {
    guard let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr) else {return}
    //MARK: remove the old polyline from the GoogleMap
    self.removePolylinePath()

    let intervalDistanceIncrement: CGFloat = 10
    let circleRadiusScale = 1 / mapView.projection.points(forMeters: 1, at: mapView.camera.target)
    var previousCircle: GMSCircle?
    for coordinateIndex in 0 ..< path.count() - 1 {
        let startCoordinate = path.coordinate(at: coordinateIndex)
        let endCoordinate = path.coordinate(at: coordinateIndex + 1)
        let startLocation = CLLocation(latitude: startCoordinate.latitude, longitude: startCoordinate.longitude)
        let endLocation = CLLocation(latitude: endCoordinate.latitude, longitude: endCoordinate.longitude)
        let pathDistance = endLocation.distance(from: startLocation)
        let intervalLatIncrement = (endLocation.coordinate.latitude - startLocation.coordinate.latitude) / pathDistance
        let intervalLngIncrement = (endLocation.coordinate.longitude - startLocation.coordinate.longitude) / pathDistance
        for intervalDistance in 0 ..< Int(pathDistance) {
            let intervalLat = startLocation.coordinate.latitude + (intervalLatIncrement * Double(intervalDistance))
            let intervalLng = startLocation.coordinate.longitude + (intervalLngIncrement * Double(intervalDistance))
            let circleCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: intervalLat, longitude: intervalLng)
            if let previousCircle = previousCircle {
                let circleLocation = CLLocation(latitude: circleCoordinate.latitude,
                                                longitude: circleCoordinate.longitude)
                let previousCircleLocation = CLLocation(latitude: previousCircle.position.latitude,
                                                        longitude: previousCircle.position.longitude)
                if mapView.projection.points(forMeters: circleLocation.distance(from: previousCircleLocation),
                                             at: mapView.camera.target) < intervalDistanceIncrement {
                    continue
                }
            }
            let circleRadius = 3 * CLLocationDistance(circleRadiusScale)
            let circle = GMSCircle(position: circleCoordinate, radius: circleRadius)
            circle.strokeWidth = 1.0
            circle.strokeColor = UIColor.Yulu.blue
            circle.fillColor = UIColor.Yulu.blue
            circle.map = mapView
            circle.userData = "root"
            polylineArray.append(circle)
            previousCircle = circle
        }
    }
}


    //MARK: - Removing dotted polyline 
    func removePolylinePath() {
    for root: GMSCircle in self.polylineArray {
        if let userData = root.userData as? String,
            userData == "root" {
            root.map = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I have taken the reference for drawing the dotted polyline from this link : https://engineering.door2door.io/dotted-polylines-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios-7b21786a0645

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a dotted polyline like below based on @Purnendu roy's code.

[Dotted polyline example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs3AB.gif)

```
private var polylineArray = [GMSMarker]()
var lastZoom: Float = 0
var walkingPathData = [[Double]]()
var kvoToken: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    self.kvoToken = self.mapView.observe(\.camera.zoom, options: .new) { [weak self] mapView, change in
        guard let self else { return }
        guard let currentZoom = change.newValue else { return }
        
        if abs(self.lastZoom - currentZoom) >= 0.35 {
            self.lastZoom = currentZoom
            self.drawWalkingPath()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.kvoToken?.invalidate()
    self.kvoToken = nil
}
```

I created a KVO token to observe the zoom value of the map in order to redraw the path whenever the zoom value changes. There is no GMSMapViewDelegate method for zoom changes. I restricted the redrawing with a 0.35 threshold value.

```
    func getWalkingPath() {
        self.viewModel.calculateWalkingPath(from: fromLocation, to: toLocation) { [weak self] model, errorMessage in
            guard let self else { return }
            if let model {
                self.walkingPathData = model.pathLocations // [[Double]]
                self.drawWalkingPath()
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Drawing dotted polyline
    func drawWalkingPath() {
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        for item in self.walkingPathData {
            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item[0], longitude: item[1])
            path.add(location)
        }
        
        self.removePolylinePath()
        
        let intervalDistanceIncrement: CGFloat = 12
        var previousMarker: GMSMarker?
        guard path.count() > 0 else { return }
        for coordinateIndex in 0 ..< path.count() - 1 {
            let startCoordinate = path.coordinate(at: coordinateIndex)
            let endCoordinate = path.coordinate(at: coordinateIndex + 1)
            let startLocation = CLLocation(latitude: startCoordinate.latitude, longitude: startCoordinate.longitude)
            let endLocation = CLLocation(latitude: endCoordinate.latitude, longitude: endCoordinate.longitude)
            let pathDistance = endLocation.distance(from: startLocation)
            let intervalLatIncrement = (endLocation.coordinate.latitude - startLocation.coordinate.latitude) / pathDistance
            let intervalLngIncrement = (endLocation.coordinate.longitude - startLocation.coordinate.longitude) / pathDistance
            for intervalDistance in 0 ..< Int(pathDistance) {
                let intervalLat = startLocation.coordinate.latitude + (intervalLatIncrement * Double(intervalDistance))
                let intervalLng = startLocation.coordinate.longitude + (intervalLngIncrement * Double(intervalDistance))
                let markerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: intervalLat, longitude: intervalLng)
                if let previousMarker = previousMarker {
                    let markerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: markerCoordinate.latitude,
                                                    longitude: markerCoordinate.longitude)
                    let previousMarkerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: previousMarker.position.latitude,
                                                            longitude: previousMarker.position.longitude)
                    if mapView.projection.points(forMeters: markerLocation.distance(from: previousMarkerLocation),
                                                 at: mapView.camera.target) < intervalDistanceIncrement {
                        continue
                    }
                }
                let marker = GMSMarker(position: markerCoordinate)
                let dotView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 9, height: 9))
                dotView.corner(dotView.frame.size.height/2)
                dotView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
                marker.iconView = dotView
                marker.map = mapView
                marker.userData = "dottedPath"
                polylineArray.append(marker)
                previousMarker = marker
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Removing dotted polyline
    func removePolylinePath() {
        for root: GMSMarker in self.polylineArray {
            if let userData = root.userData as? String,
               userData == "dottedPath" {
                root.map = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

I used GMSMarker along with UIView based circles instead of GMSCircle. Thus, I achieved to have static sized circles regardless of zoom level. When zoomed in, the frequency of the dots will be increased, otherwise vice versa.

To increase the distance between dots, increase the intervalDistanceIncrement value. To edit the dots, you can change the size and background color of UIView object.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the following link: http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/ that may be of help.

```
func drawRoute() {
    let route = mapTasks.overviewPolyline["points"] as String

    let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)
    routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    routePolyline.map = viewMap
}
```

At the end of the above snippet, we necessarily have to set the map to the routePolyline property.

```
func displayRouteInfo() {
    lblInfo.text = mapTasks.totalDistance + "\n" + mapTasks.totalDuration
}
```

Comment: i already have this in my code but this code not draw a dotted polyline.

Answer (score 0):

As I know is not possible yet :- (. You can draw dashed lines via GMSStyleSpans, but not dotted lines (Google Maps  vers. 2.2.0). If I'm wrong please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

finally after struggling a lot I found

```
extension GMSMapView {    
    func drawDottedLines(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
                         to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        clear()
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.add(from)
        path.add(to)

        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        let lengths: [NSNumber] = [10, 10]
        let styles = [
          GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.black),
          GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.clear)
        ]

        polyline.spans =  GMSStyleSpans(polyline.path!,
                                        styles,
                                        lengths,
                                        GMSLengthKind.rhumb)
        
        polyline.map = self
     }
    }
```

above solutions works for me as I used the trick for using multicolor polyline with clear color :). Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

//Method-1
To create a dashed polyline in the google maps. This should be useful.

```
 let polyline1 = GMSPolyline.init(path: path1)
 let mapView = forMapView
 polyline1.strokeWidth = 4
 polyline1.strokeColor = UIColor.red
 polyline1.map = mapView
 let styles = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.clear),
               GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.red)]
 let lengths: [NSNumber] = [2, 2]
 polyline1.spans = GMSStyleSpans(polyline1.path!,
                                 styles,
                                 lengths,
                                 GMSLengthKind.rhumb)
 var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
 for index in 1...(path1?.count())! {
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate((path1?.coordinate(at: index))!)
 }
 mapView?.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
```

//Method-2 To create a polyline with circle in google maps. This piece of code should be useful.

```
 let dotRadius: CGFloat = 5
 let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: .zero,
                                           size: CGSize(
            width: dotRadius * 2,
            height: dotRadius * 2
           )
      )
 )
 let dot = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(
            width: dotRadius * 2,
            height: dotRadius * 2)).image { context in
                    UIColor.red.setFill()
                    dotPath.fill()
                }
  let interval = 3
  for i in stride(from: 0, to: path1?.count() ?? 0, by: interval) {
           let coordinate = path1?.coordinate(at: i)
           let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate!)
           marker.icon = dot
           marker.map = mapView
  }
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
 for index in 1...(path1?.count())! {
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate((path1?.coordinate(at: index))!)
 }
 mapView?.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
```